# Step by Step Tic Tac Toe Android sample failure

Tags: android, eclipse

After reading a zillion posts on how to make a referenced library work with Android-Eclipse I must declare failure to run the provided sample tic-tac-toe, which is split into two projects **TicTacToeLib** (marked as library) and **TicTacToeMain** (which uses TicTacToeLib)

1. I first <strike>imported</strike> created TicTacToeLib into Eclipse (File->New->Other->Android->Android sample project->TicTacToeLib)
2. Then <strike>imported</strike> created TicTacToeMain into Eclipse (File->New->Other->Android->Android sample project->TicTacToeMain)
3. Followed the instructions on the [Android Developers site](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject) on how to setup and reference a library project

Here I encounter the first obstacle, because on one hand the site mentions that `<user-library>` should be used, but the example Manifest for **TicTacToeMain** does not contain any `<uses-library>` element.
Either way the example does not run.

Without `<user-library>` element the project does not even compile:

[image]

If I add the tictactoelib.jar to the build path manually (`Add JARs...`), which is **not** part of the instructed steps in the Android Developers page, the errors dissapear, only the warnings remain.  Running the app exits with failure (" *Unfortunately Tic Tac Toe Sample has stopped* "):

```
04-08 16:05:24.762: E/dalvikvm(3741): Could not find class 'com.example.android.tictactoe.library.GameActivity', referenced from method com.example.android.tictactoe.MainActivity.startGame
04-08 16:05:24.762: W/dalvikvm(3741): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 17 (Lcom/example/android/tictactoe/library/GameActivity;) in Lcom/example/android/tictactoe/MainActivity;
04-08 16:05:24.767: D/dalvikvm(3741): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0002
04-08 16:05:24.877: V/PhoneStatusBar(166): setLightsOn(true)
04-08 16:05:24.937: D/gralloc_goldfish(3741): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-08 16:05:25.017: I/Process(89): Sending signal. PID: 3741 SIG: 3
04-08 16:05:25.027: I/dalvikvm(3741): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-08 16:05:25.037: I/dalvikvm(3741): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-08 16:05:25.058: I/ActivityManager(89): Displayed com.example.android.tictactoe/.MainActivity: +1s368ms
04-08 16:05:25.317: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(89): setKernelCountSet(10013, 0) failed with errno -2
04-08 16:05:27.857: D/AndroidRuntime(3741): Shutting down VM
04-08 16:05:27.857: W/dalvikvm(3741): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
04-08 16:05:27.918: E/AndroidRuntime(3741): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 16:05:27.918: E/AndroidRuntime(3741): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.android.tictactoe.library.GameActivity
04-08 16:05:27.918: E/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at com.example.android.tictactoe.MainActivity.startGame(MainActivity.java:51)
04-08 16:05:27.918: E/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at com.example.android.tictactoe.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:50)
04-08 16:05:27.918: E/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at com.example.android.tictactoe.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)
04-08 16:05:27.918: E/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
04-08 16:05:27.918: E/AndroidRuntime(3741):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
```

---

Adding the following line to the TicTacToeMain manifest:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.example.android.tictactoe.library"/>
```

does not even launch the app:

```
[2013-04-08 19:13:03 - TicTacToeMain] Android Launch!
[2013-04-08 19:13:03 - TicTacToeMain] adb is running normally.
[2013-04-08 19:13:03 - TicTacToeMain] Performing com.example.android.tictactoe.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-04-08 19:13:03 - TicTacToeMain] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Smartphone_ics'
[2013-04-08 19:13:03 - TicTacToeMain] Uploading TicTacToeMain.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-04-08 19:13:03 - TicTacToeMain] Installing TicTacToeMain.apk...
[2013-04-08 19:13:06 - TicTacToeMain] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2013-04-08 19:13:06 - TicTacToeMain] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-04-08 19:13:06 - TicTacToeMain] Launch canceled!
```

I tried other things, none solved the problem:

- Changed the target TicTacToeMain version to 15, to 10
- Added the TicTacToeLib as User Library in the build path
- Created a libs folder for TicTacToeMain, and copied tictactoelib.jar, did not solve, imported the tictactoelib.jar uising Import..., no sugar

The reason I want this sample to work, besides understadning how to the mechnaism for referenced libraries work, is that I want to create a complex app, using many referenced libraries and if I cannot make this silly sample work, then I will not be able to.

One more point, adding the reference library project to TicTacToeMain:

[image]

It does not stick, I press `Apply` as instructed, then `OK`. But when I open the Project's properties again (no run, no compile, just reopen):

[image]

Maybe this is the real symptom, but I don't know what else to try.
I use Eclipse 4.2.1, Android SDK 21.1, Java IDE 1.5.1
Target Java Compliance level is 1.6
I tried several AVDs emulators, all show the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This voodoo process finally got the project to compile and run properly.
I still don't know what is it that made the difference, so if you understand, please edit this asnwer and complete the explanation.

**Process**:
After many unsuccsessful tries I decided to export the JAR file from TicTacToeLib project and add the exported JAR to the TicTacToeMain project. Doing that solved the ClassNotFound exception but created a new problem: duplicates resource IDs ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918441/generating-really-unique-ids-for-imported-jar)).
So I deleted the imported JAR from the libs directory and from the build path and just by a desperate act I went to TicTacToeMain propeties->Android and added TicTacToeLib as reference. I've done this before at least 4 times and it did not work. I don't know why I even tried it again.
**This time I noticed at the edge of my vision that something changed in the Package Explorer pane in Eclipse. I discovered that something was added under TicTactToeMain/gen. A com.example.tictactoe.library folder containing a R.java file with renumbered ID's that do not conflict with the main project's IDs.** This has never happened before in my other attemps to add a reference library. So I run the app and this time it ran OK.
As I said, at  this point this is voodoo to me, I don't know what I did different now than in the previous 4 times I tried the same.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I just loaded up the TicTacToeMain and TicTacToeLib via New Project Android->Android Sample Project. The only thing I needed to change was to go into TicTacToeMain project properties, go to Java Build Path, select Libraries and remove the 'bad' library/jar reference. After that I get a clean (well warnings only) compile.

Answer (score 0):

It is just to do a new-project-android->Android Sample Project->Tictactoemain/lib. Do not import, just a new project and it works. In any case right click on project name -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties and in the menu Project-> Clean.
Maybe another clean workspace or new emulator device (is it correctly setup?)? You have all java, android sdk, adt and so on? I have no such problems.

Comment: I did RightClick->Android Tools->Fix Project, then Project clean, but same result. It did not fix the problem. I wrote `import` but if you read afterthat you see I created new projects.

Comment: Since you have no such problems, can you tell me which steps did you do to reference the library from TicTacToeMain? Which versions of Eclipse-Android SDK do you use?

Comment: Eclipse kepler http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php sdk 4.2 the newest one

Answer (score 0):

#### about the reference library

This error means that your `TicTacToLib` is using from another project, to solve this error you have to :

- copy the `tictactolib`.
- delete that project which is using the `tictactolib` and check the `remove from the hard disk`.
- past the `tictactolib` to the old path.

try again and the error will be gone.

#### Note:

ofc, you can just un import the library from the project which is using it right now without deleting that project.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer. I installed specifically these 2 projects (TicTacToeLib and TicTacToeMain) from scrach, there are no other projects using them in my workspace.

Comment: I had the same problem with the same error (lib can't be included), in my case I was using that lib in another project, bty click on the "X" error sign and tell us the error message which will appear

Comment: Do you mean the red "X" in the reference library picture I posted? Click, or double click do not bring up nothing. I can remove it and add it again, and it becomes green, but as I said, it does not stick, becoming red again next time you open that window